# Create a rectangle box with fixed width of rounded?

Tags: blender, rounded-corners, cube, 3d-modelling, 3d-model

I am creating a simple 3d model like a brick. I try to add bavel for rounded corner and edge with same width. But I did it failed, each face with different rounded curve. Can anyone teach me how to did it well.

my 3d model:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q7njgz161u2trof/untitled.dae?dl=0
```

my model width x height x depth = 2.1 x 6 x 1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After you apply transformation to your object hit Ctrl+A then select apply Scale after that you can apply bevel modofier and it works fine.
For any modifier to work properly after transformation always apply scale